# How to extract the value before the last underscore in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need to extract the value before the last underscore in shell script.

Example:

```
Input:   first_second_third_mmddyyy.csv
Output: first_second_third

Input: first_second_mmddyy.csv
Output: first_second
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/_[^_]*$//g' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ echo "first_second_third_mmddyyy.csv" | sed 's/_[^_]*$//g'
first_second_third

$ echo "first_second_mmddyy.csv" | sed 's/_[^_]*$//g'
first_second
```

Comment: @smisra3, Glad it work for you. I see that you never accepted answers for any of your question that has been answered. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted if your problem is already solved. You can do it clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. See [HelpCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/someone-answers) if you have any questions.

Comment: minor nitpick, no need `g` flag as the expression can only match once

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
while read -r line; do echo "${line%_*}"; done < file
# ...........................^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use awk or cut as below;

```
awk -F '_' 'NF{NF-=1};1' file

echo "first_second_third_mmddyyy.csv" | rev | cut -d '_' -f2- | rev
```

Eg;

```
$ echo "first_second_third_mmddyyy.csv"  | awk -F '_' 'NF{NF-=1};1'
first second third
```

NF is a variable containing the number of fields in a line.

NF-=1 is subtracting one from the NF variable, to remove last field

Comment: this will not work unless you set `OFS` to be `_` as well